# image crop in ios using BJImageCropper

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, crop

I am using BJImageCropper for image crop in iOS, but when I am touching on the image's last corner, it's automatically updating the height and width on the opposite side.

[image]

Example code is https://github.com/barrettj/BJImageCropper/zipball/master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the commit I just pushed.  Should be fixed there.

Comment: Hi BarrettJ, if i want to add crop as 1:1 ratio. like square image crop then how to do that?

Comment: @BarrettJ There is already issue when cropping image that too wide and less height. The image gets added extra width and height. Extra black image shows there.

Comment: Use PEPhotoCropEditor (https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/PEPhotoCropEditor). It is better than BJImageCropper.

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug in the code. Contact the author to correct the errors :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use another option for croping Image that is ContextRect

A short Example of it is :

```
CGRect contextRect = CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contextRect.size);

[self.view.layer renderInContext : UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([viewImage CGImage], contextRect);

UIImage * savedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:1.0 orientation:viewImage.imageOrientation];
```

You can edit the x,y origin and width n height of the view according to your image.